# Float.toString() problem in component vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I´m tying to send data to other component in vuejs 2.

In my first component, if insert with GraphQL it´s result is ok, i´m doing redirect with router push and send data:

```
const today = new Date();
        const date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
        const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        let fechaHoraActual = date +' '+ time;
        let magnitud = parseFloat(data.magnitud);
        let importe = parseFloat(data.importe);
        let datos = {
                      "anio_dec":data.anio_dec, "mes_dec":data.mes_dec, "anio_mag":data.anio_mag,
                      "mes_mag":data.mes_mag, "cod_empresa":data.cod_empresa, "unidad":data.unidad,
                      "actividad":data.actividad, "magnitud": magnitud, "importe": importe, 
                      "updated_at": fechaHoraActual, "usuario_id":this.usuario.id
                    };
        this.$router.push({ name: 'PaginaDatosAportacionesManuales', query: { datos } });
```

in my destiny component i´m filling array that this array it´s returned and send to table for to show data:

```
recibirDatos(data){

      if (typeof data.datos !== 'undefined') {
        if(typeof data.datos == 'object'){
          var result = Object.entries(data.datos);

          console.log(typeof data.datos.magnitud);

          for(let key in result){
            if(result.hasOwnProperty(key)){
              this.listaDatos.push(result[key]);
            }
          }
          
          console.log(this.listaDatos);
        }
      }
    }
```

And in my table i have:

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="listaTodosDatos" class="elevation-1 header-data-table"
          hide-default-footer :loading="cargandoDatos" :no-data-text="textNoData" :loading-text="loadingText"
          :disable-pagination="true" :search="search">
          <template v-slot:body="{ items }" v-if="listaTodosDatos.length > 0">
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
                <td > {{ item.nombre }}</td>

                <td > {{ item.anio_dec }}</td>

                <td > {{ item.mes_dec }}</td>

                <td > {{ item.anio_mag }} </td>

                <td > {{ item.mes_mag }} </td>

                <td > {{ item.cod_empresa }} </td>

                <td > {{ item.unidad }} </td>

                <td > {{ item.actividad }} </td>

                <td > <span v-html="$options.filters.formatMilesConDecimales(item.magnitud.toString())"></span> </td>

                <td > <span v-html="$options.filters.formatImporte(item.importe)"></span> </td>
                
                <td > {{ item.updated_at | formatfecha }} </td>
                
                <td > {{ item.usuario }} </td>
```

My problem it´s in `$options.filters.formatMilesConDecimales(item.magnitud.toString())` that web-browser console return `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')"` and i don´t know that i´m doing wrong.

in this line i´m calling to `formatMilesConDecimales` that have this:

```
filters?: { [key: string]: Function }
```

One interface ComponentOptions... but i don´t know that do it very well. This project i´t not mine, i´m modifying it

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: It seems like `item.magnitud` is undefined and don't have a string content.

Comment: @NilsKähler thanks for your response, but in console i have this parameter with data, for example 15:  7: (2) ['magnitud', 15, __ob__: Observer] this is result from console

Comment: ```15: 7: (2) ['magnitud', 15, ob: Observer]``` if this is showed in your console, then you cannot use *toString()* because there is an object on your data.